# How to draw two figures in one using networkx?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, networkx, axes

I am trying to draw two figures together, but they come out displaced one with respect to the other.
First, I define the badminton pitch with a function.

```
def bad_courtV(ax=None, color='black'):
    # If an axes object isn't provided to plot onto, just get current one
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    
    ax.plot([0,61],[0,0], color=color)
    ax.plot([61,61], [0,134],color=color)
    ax.plot([61,0], [134,134],color=color)
    ax.plot([0,0], [134,0],color=color)
    ax.plot([0,61],[67,67], color=color, linewidth=4)

    ax.plot([4.6,4.6],[0,134],color=color)
    ax.plot([56.4,56.4],[0,134], color=color)
    ax.plot([61,0],[126.4,126.4], color=color)
    ax.plot([0,61],[7.6,7.6], color=color)

    ax.plot([61,0],[86.8,86.8], color=color)
    ax.plot([0,61],[47.2,47.2], color=color)

    ax.plot([30.5,30.5],[47.2,0], color=color)
    ax.plot([30.5,30.5],[86.8,134], color=color)

    
    return ax
```

and the plot a network of a sequence of strokes:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))

pos_bad = pos_bad
ax=bad_courtV()
color='black'
nx.draw_networkx(B, pos_bad,with_labels=True,width=0.25,ax=ax,edge_color='gray',arrows=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The results is a figure like that:
[One figure is in left bottom corner and the other in the right upper corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl84z.png)

Of course, I would like that the network is drawn on the pitch.
Can anyone help me with how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: The position depends on the contents of `pos_bad`. How are these positions chosen?  Maybe you could add about 50 to their `x` and about 70 to their `y` coordinate, to be a bit more similar to the court?

Comment: You are totally right @JohanC, now I understand the problem. I have designed pos_bad using other references distances (-62,62) instead of (0,134) for example. Thanks a lot.